# Android EditText's text value to set the selected item in the Spinner

Tags: java, android

Hello if you would kindly help me with my problem. Basically, my goal is to set the selected item in the spinner by getting the value of the EditText's text. The spinner has been populated already from an xml string array. I've used TextWatcher's AfterTextChanged method to monitor any changes on the EditText's text value. Here is my code but it seems like its not working.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.addTextChangedListener(editTextListener);

private TextWatcher editTextListener= new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        if (editText .getText().equals("1")) {
            spinner1.setSelection(0);
            // 1 on my spinner is letter A
        } else if(editText .getText().equals("2")) {
            spinner1.setSelection(1);
           // 2 on my spinner is letter B
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The letter is not on the alphabet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a listener not linking the listener to the edittext you want.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.addTextChangedListener(editTextListener);

private TextWatcher editTextListener= new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        if (editText .getText().equals("1")) {
            spinner1.setSelection(0);
            // 1 on my spinner is letter A
        } else if(editText .getText().equals("2")) {
            spinner1.setSelection(1);
           // 2 on my spinner is letter B
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The letter is not on the alphabet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}

edittext.addTextChangedListener(editTextListener);
```

I think this what you want.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering! Is it possible to make a TextWatcher not an anonymous inner class?

Comment: You can, you need to create an object for the TextWatcher and then you can bind it with the edittext. "edittext.addTextChangedListener(obj)"

Comment: Okay thank you for your suggestion. Would you mind giving me an example on how to do it? I hope I'm on the right track. -_-